# How to get such font style?

Tags: fonts, fontspec

I want to use the following font style, but I do not know how to.

[image]

I have tried using `\texttt`, but I found it is too bold. I want to more slimmer font.

My test case is

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\texttt{"Between.Between.between", "Between.Between.between-X"} 
\end{document}
```

The output is

[image]

Much appreciated to anyone who could give me some help.

Comment: You can use `\texttt` in an equation:  `\( F(T) = \{ \texttt{"Some typewriter text"} \} \) `

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please provide a MWE that we know which settings and packages you're using and what you've already tried. Furthermore, it helps us to help you. It looks like you're showing lines of code. There exist special packages for formatting code.

Comment: @Thruston But I found `\texttt` is too bold, I want the font slimmer than `\texttt`. Could you give me some advice?

Comment: [Welcome to TEX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/82917) Please provide a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/82917). If you want a lighter version of `\texttt` you should use another font. But since you are not sharing any code which shows your setup there is no way of suggesting something meaningful.

Comment: The default `\textt` is Latin Modern Mono. You want to pick a different font, for example, `\setmonofont{Inconsolata}`. You might be able to identify the one here on IdentiFont.

Comment: @Davislor Thanks for your help! I have solved the problem!